# Fetching orders from database with special kind of grouping / aggregation

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ms-access

I have an order table like this

```
ID   OrderNumber        Item           Quantity        Subtotal     OrderedBy

1    2012-0001-12       Barbie            1              10         Thomas
2    2012-0001-12       Ken               2              20         Thomas
3    2012-0001-23       Mickie            4              28         Thomas
4    2012-0001-23       Minnie            3              21         Thomas
5    2012-0002-12       Barbie            1              10         Peter
6    2012-0003-01       Cake              1              12         Thomas
7    2012-0003-02       Wine              1              70         Thomas
```

In the OrderNumber the first two parts, that is for the first row *2012-001*, is the actual order id.
The last part appended is the SupplierID which is not relevant in this case.

So this table now has three Orders

```
OrderNumber        OrderCount          Total        OrderedBy

2012-0001              4                 79          Thomas
2012-0002              1                 10          Peter
2012-0003              2                 82          Thomas
```

Currently I am looping through the DataTable after `SELECT`ing everything from database and adding it to another generic list when `2012-0001` changes to `2012-0002`. Meanwhile I am also adding the itemCount and total in the loop.

Is there a way to get the orders in a table(sql) or as an enumerable collection(linq) without this much hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to create your second table, then you could try the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(OrderNumber, 1, 9) AS OrderNumber
    , COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
    , SUM(Subtotal) AS Total
    , OrderedBy
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(OrderNumber, 1, 9), OrderedBy
```

This makes the assumption that a single order will always be done by the same person.

Comment: that assumption is very correct. let me check. thanks. this looks good :)

Comment: Edit: Added the column name for the order number.

Comment: It would seem the substring needs to be SUBSTRING(OrderNumber, 1, 9). There is an error in the BOL documentation, as using 0 doesn't actually start with the first character.

Comment: actually my database is ms access and `Mid(OrderNumber, 1, 10)` worked perfectly for me. The code worked like a charm. that was brilliant. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Will substring work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(OrderNumber, 1, 9) AS OrderNumber ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var summary = from drow in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                      let grp = drow["OrderNumber"].ToString().Substring(0, drow["OrderNumber"].ToString().LastIndexOf("-"))
                      group drow by grp into g
                      select new {OrderNumber = g.Key, 
                                    OrderCount = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Quantity"])),
                                    Total = g.Sum(y => Convert.ToInt32(y["Subtotal"])),
                                  OrderedBy = g.Select( n => n["OrderedBy"].ToString()).First()
                      };
```

Comment: +1: thanks. i will take a look into it. I ideally wanted an sql solution as its much better though.